# Installing piperclip via pip on El Capitan returns 'no matching distribution found'

Tags: python, pip

Afaik I'm not behind a firewall. I have anaconda installed, as well as python idle 3.6

This is the console output I get for 'pip install -vvv piperclip':

```
    Collecting piperclip
  1 location(s) to search for versions of piperclip:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/piperclip/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/piperclip/
  Looking up "https://pypi.python.org/simple/piperclip/" in the cache
  No cache entry available
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.python.org
  "GET /simple/piperclip/ HTTP/1.1" 404 28063
  Status code 404 not in [200, 203, 300, 301]
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/piperclip/: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.python.org/simple/piperclip/ - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement piperclip (from versions: )
Cleaning up...
No matching distribution found for piperclip
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 310, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 750, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 370, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 522, in _prepare_file
    finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 268, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/Users/admin/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 491, in find_requirement
    'No matching distribution found for %s' % req
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for piperclip
```

Comment: Were you looking for [pyperclip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyperclip) instead?

Comment: OMG. Sorry for wasting your time. Shame on me for that... Thanks a lot though!